# chrome.storage.sync doesn't sync between machines

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-storage

I have a simple extensions that saves some data to chrome storage

```
var dt = new Date();
var item = {};
item[$('#qteSymb').text() + "-" + guid()] = $('#newnote').val() + "-:-" + $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dt) + " " + dt.getHours() + ":" + (dt.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + dt.getMinutes() : dt.getMinutes());           
chrome.storage.sync.set(item, function(){
    renderNotes();
});
```

This works fine locally - my extension is working as intended - but it doesn't sync back to another computer. I am assuming the sync is ON on both computers because the bookmarks, extensions, etc. sync just fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I finally figured this out.
When not using Chrome Web Store your manifest file should include a key (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#key)

```
...
"key":"myawesomeextension"
...
```

Without this every time you install the extension on a different device (through chrome://extensions/ --> Load unpacked extension) it gets a new id and therefore the data being synced doesn't get matched to the correct extension - same extension with different ids = two different extensions in the eyes of Chrome.

There is no need for a key once the extension is in Chrome Web Store. Hope this helps somebody keep some hair at some point.

Comment: Failed to load extension from: ~\Documents\.. Value 'key' is missing or invalid.

Comment: Do you know if this is still an issue today ?

Comment: This is still and issue today and using a `key` solved my issue. You cannot put any string in there though. It has to be a valid Chrome extension string. You can find these strings from your extension if you load it up and call `chrome.runtime.getURL('')`.

Comment: Adding the key did NOT solve my issue... the data is still not being synced...

Comment: @ykonda you have to make sure you update your extension in both machines.